# ERD - Multiple FKs with only one of them being filled for each record

Tags: database-design, schema, erd

I'm designing a database schema for a music platform.

Some of the entities as follows:

- track
- album
- band
- artist

A "track" can have an "artist". It can also have a "band" which makes the artist FK `null`.

Same goes with "album", an "album" can have an "artist" but if the "album" is from a "band" then the artist FK will be `null`. That's because an "album" by a "band" can't also have a single "artist" as well.

The two(or three) FKs will never be filled together and only one of them must be filled for each record.

Is this a good design practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good design practice is to implement and enforce the rules of the problem domain. So if your rules lead to this design then that's what you've got. Having mutually exclusive values is not uncommon.

They can be implemented in different ways. One is as you describe. Another is to use table inheritance. With this you would have tables `track`, `artist` and `band` as you do currently but also `band_track` and `artist_track`. These will have only the foreign keys specific to themselves, defined as `not null`. The problem then becomes one of enforcing exclusion between `band_track` and `artist_track`. Personally, I don't think this approach actually improves our position much.

For my two cents I'd go with what you have. Declare CHECK constraints to prevent illegal combinations within a row (or use triggers if you absolutely must).